# class selector is not working inside struts form

Tags: xhtml

i have struts form which stuts textfield and normal html input tag here cssClass attribute inside stuts textfield working but class selector is not working normal html input tag

```
<s:form id="Form" cssClass="form-horizontal" theme="css_xhtml"  action="saveStudentMarks">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Class</label>
<div class="col-xs-5">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="className" id="studentclassInModal" readonly="readonly"/>
</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">                    
<label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone</label>                     
<div class="col-xs-3">                  
<s:textfield  name="parentDTO.parentMobileNumber" cssClass="form-control marks"  maxlength="10"/>
</div>  
</div>  
</s:form>
```

Comment: have done some changes and displayed answer below pls check. added code to get the percentage as well https://jsfiddle.net/4mwbudob/1/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the loop, change `html()` to `val()` to set the value of the text input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".marks").on('input', function() {
    calculateSum();
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".marks").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
};
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/4mwbudob/

Comment: This code is working as i am expected but when i place this code why keyup function itself is not called

Comment: what keyup function?, i change the keyup event to a input event so you can paste numbers and the form still updates

Comment: are you sure you have jquery added to your page?

Comment: i have struts form inside class element is not working

Comment: what's a "struts form inside class element"

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
$('#sum').focus(function(){    // It works on when textbox having id sum get focus
     //var marks = [];
     $('.marks').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
        // push the marks in marks array and add them and show where you want
     });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nse0c4ky/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Have done some changes,

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mwbudob/1/)

Use `.val()` for inputs instead of `.html()`

```
$("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Calulates Percentage as well

```
$("#per").val((sum/100).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.each()` in `jquery` is used to check one by one of specific element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".marks").keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".marks").each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    console.log(sum)
}
```

Comment: $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2)); will not do anything. please check before posting

Comment: i only get this answer fiddle after posting question but in when i place this code in project keyup function is not working why

Comment: @jancy, please look after console message what is it showing. Maybe there is another js error in your project that preventing this event.